# How to implement Alerts in Jaeger?

Tags: jaeger

We want to monitor the status of our microservices. Our idea is to use Jaeger to monitor the information we get from Opentelemetry and to be notified (through emails) in case some parts of the flow are slow or not working. From my understanding, there are no alerting systems in Jaeger.

How can these alerts be implemented?